# C# Share int Between people

Tags: c#

What I want to do is share this int between all the users in this list.

```
List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();
Random Rand = new Random();
int Reward = Rand.GetNext(1, 5000);
```

Is there a way I can share this int the 'Reward' int between all the players in that list? Player is a class btw that holds a dictionary of all my players.

And it must be full like it cant be a decimal since its a int. Is there a way to share it and to give a bigger cut to the vip users?

```
foreach (Player players in Players)
{
    if (players.info.isVip)
    {
        //bigger cut here
    }
    else
    {
        players.info.money = players.info.money + cut_here;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is always shared between all players make it a static int in the class.

Comment: Thst foreach look is in a void. The int is a param of that void 'Reward' public static void ShareCut(int Reward)

Comment: I'm curious why you want to share access to the Reward int itself to players instead of figuring out the relative cuts ahead of time. I'd be inclined to get the reward first. Figure out the number of VIP vs non-VIP players, apply my "cut" rules, then walk the collection and assign `.money += cut_here`. What's the rationale for trying to do this all in the same step?

Comment: this is a poorly written question... "share" means something specific in programming but what you want to do is divvy up the value...  and that's really a basic math question not a programming one

Answer (score 1):

Make `Reward` a `static` variable like

```
static int Reward;
Reward = Rand.GetNext(1,5000);
```

Comment: This doesn't help with what I want to do. I want to split that Reward int between all the players and give them all a cut enless they are vip if they are give them a little bit bigger cut.

Answer (score 0):

To make int split between all players make 2 static int variables. One will be the count for how many players there are. One will be the variable that will be the total amount to split. Then call a static void to loop through all players and give them the totalamount / totalplayers.

If you store the players in a list then you don't need the count variable. Just use list.count.

Comment: But how do I get how much each player are ment to have? How do I get like for example 10% of that int.. for how much % each player should have.

Comment: Why two ints? If the there are 2 people who get a cut of 1 which is possible, you need a double.

Comment: Simple arithmetic. You can have all sorts of ways to divide the amount up. Try a few methods and see what you like best.

Comment: If you want to give each player a specific percentage then times the amount by .1 and give that to the player.

Comment: @sybran I'm not sure why I said int for the amount to give. That should e a double. Thanks